# Can't Load PHP in Apache

Tags: php, html, database, phpmyadmin, apache2

i have a database in phpmyadmin called "bddiscos", and I 'm trying to use the following code to make the connection:

```
$cnx = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("Error!");
$db = mysql_select_db("bddiscos");
```

What gives me the following error , according to the apache error.log:

```
[Fri Jul 08 12:46:23.533006 2016] [:error] [pid 6664] [client 127.0.0.1:44760] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

And I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `mysql`extension is not enabled in your server. On the other hand, `mysql` is deprecated now and you should not use it anymore on your projects. I would recommend you to use either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

In case still if you want to use `mysql`, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php7.0-mysql
```

Then restart your Apache server,

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: How I can activate it in apache?

Comment: what's your Apache and PHP version? @federicoGuastadisegni

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.4.23  ...  PHP Version 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1